# Weird twice execution in the double for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I got this weird bug, which is not 100% reproducible, for like half a week and still cannot figure it out. Hopefully someone can give me some instruction.

So I'm building this Tetris game. In this well grid, which is actually a 2d array, whenever the tetromino drops at the very bottom(it hits another tetromino or the boundary of the well), I transfer the grid of that, which contains four square blocks, into the well grid. Normally it behaves well, but sometimes after the game, the shape doesn't look correct anymore.

And here is the function with comment:

```
function transferTetroGridIntoWell({ grid, tetroGrid, tetroPosition, color }) {
  let newGrid = [...grid]
  let relativeX, relativeY
  // the tetroGrid could be a 2d array like:
  // [1,1,0]
  // [1,1,0], in which 1 indicates a block, and 0 is none

  for (let row = 0; row < tetroGrid.length; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < tetroGrid[0].length; col++) {
      if (!tetroGrid[row][col]) continue
      // the index of the array relative to the well grid 
      relativeX = tetroPosition.x + col
      relativeY = tetroPosition.y + row

      // assign the color to the according square block in the well grid
      newGrid[relativeY][relativeX] = color
    }
  }
  return newGrid
}
```

Here is the problem:

Since each of the tetromino contains only 4 square blocks, the `newGrid[relativeY][relativeX] = color` should only be executed for four times, which is true from what it looks like in the debugger. But sometimes it sometimes look like this assignment gets executed twice before the it is called again.

Here is the debug screenshot:

**before execution:**

[image]

**1st time after execution:(and this is where the weird thing happens, there are two `#f6d42b` inserted into the well, not only grid[8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12PwJ.png), but also grid[7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12PwJ.png))**
[image]

**2nd time after execution:(still double execution)**
[image]

**3rd time after execution:**
[image]

**4th time after execution:**
[image]

**Four times of execution inserted 6 square blocks. How could that happen??!!**

Full source code: https://github.com/thomasyimgit/Tetris

REALLY APPRECIATED for whoever finished reading this long post!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's all about mutating the data.

Using the spread operator to copy an array is only a shallow copy. Thus, it's possible that two rows are referencing to the same row of the grid. And when you do the assignment, the two rows update simultaneously, which seems like double execution.

I modify the first line in the `transferTetroGridIntoWell` function to this and it fixes the problem:

`let newGrid = grid.map(r => r.map(c => c))`

MUTATING is EVIL.